# How to display the value of the future checkbox element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, checkbox

I'm appending multiple checkbox like this:

```
$(".btn-sample").on("click", function() {
  $(".container").append(
    '<input class="check-sample" type="checkbox" 
    value="'+check_value+'"/>'
  );
});
```

My problem is that my other button cannot get the value of the new checkbox below:

```
 $(".show-checkbox").click(function() {
   var arr = [];
   $('.check-sample:checked').each(function () {
       arr[i++] = $(this).val();
   });
   console.log(arr);
 });
```

Thank for helping in advance!

Comment: Your fiddle is different

Comment: Your other button is looking for a "ads_Checkbox" class on the checkbox (not sure how much the details in the jsfiddle are relevant here, though).

Comment: This fiddle code is pretty unoptimalized, and unthinking. If you click on the several times, you have a hole in the begining of the array. (4 * x-1) empty array slots where x is the button click if all checkbox selected.
back to the current question, you need other code.

Comment: I edited my question, kindly read. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

for dynamically added elements try this:

```
$("body").on("click",".btn-sample", function() {
  $(".container").append(
    '<input class="check-sample" type="checkbox" 
    value="'+check_value+'"/>'
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify `input[type=checkbox]` selector for `.container`. Because you are appending the checkboxes to this div and it has different case from your fiddle.

```js
$(".btn-sample").on("click", function() {
  var check_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  $(".container").append(
    '<input class="check-sample" type="checkbox" value="'+check_value+'"/>'
  );
});
 $('#getValue').click(function () {
       $('.container input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
           console.log($(this).val()); 
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "container"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn-sample">Append</button>
<button type="button" id="getValue">Get Value</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the newly created elements as children of `.container` which is a process called "delegation."

Review [this document](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on event delegation by jQuery.

You can also take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbtrzozt/2/) that I did a while back.

In short, you have to refer to the parent element first.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-checkbox', function () {
   var arr = [];
   $('.check-sample:checked').each(function () {
       arr[i++] = $(this).val();
   });
   console.log(arr);
 });
```

Comment: The result is empty array